# PHP single checkbox sticky form - session

Tags: php, forms, validation, checkbox

I am having a problem with a checkbox that I need to be part of a stick form, that will be remembered via a session so that the user can navigate through different pages and still have their checkbox selection remember for when they return.

The checkbox is to be clicked by the user if they want to have their delivery details the same as the billing details they entered at the top of the form. No need to worry about how I assign the delivery details to the same as the billing details as I do that on later pages.

Note: Javascript is completely out for this, don't think its needed anyway but just a heads up :). This is one of those sticky-forms that posts to itself untill all criteria are met(`$flag == "ok"`) and then send the user to the next page.

I will now provide what I believe to be the relevant code:

PHP (this section of code may not be relevant but I am including it as I am as can be seen, setting what the final `$_SESSION['sameasbilling']` will be before I send the user to the next page(`order-confirm.php`)

```
if ($flag == "ok"){
    $sameasbilling = cleanString($_POST['sameasbilling']);
    $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = $sameasbilling;

    if (!headers_sent()){
        //send user to next page
        header("Location: order-confirm.php");
    }else{
        echo "Not Sent";
    }
}
```

HTML/PHP

```
<p>Same as billing address? &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="sameasbilling" name="sameasbilling" value="1" 
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['sameasbilling'])) {
    print ' checked="checked"';
    $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = "1";
} else {
    $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = "";
}
?> />
```

As far as I can see the most important piece of code is above where I try and figure out whether to output checked='checked' or not and whether to reset/set the 'sameasbilling' session value.

P.S I have been over and over this loads of times and so the IF statement I have in my input element is pretty scruffy, but at the moment does remember your selection when you stay on the same page and receive errors but when you move to the next page and return your selection is not remembered and I'm aware that I do not have any code that would actually do that at all, but I'm hoping someone could suggest how I can achieve that.

Comment: it looks like you've answered the question, or actually... there is no question.

Comment: +1 and always `exit()` after setting `header(Location)`

Comment: @soyuka *after setting header("location"); You wouldn't want to die after header("Content-type") for example!

Comment: You're right there actually is no question mark on this post. I'll amend that now. But my question is how do I make that IF statement account for if a session variable is set and to remember it and also allow the form to change the sessions variable if the user the user unticks the checkbox. Does that make sense?

Comment: So:
    if (!headers_sent())
{
    //send user to next page
    header("Location: order-confirm.php");
    exit();
}

Comment: I think you're confused about what `headers_sent()` is for. I have updated my answer

Comment: @popnoodles Yeah seams logic I've edited sorry.

Comment: popnoodles, you are probably correct. Can you help with my problem at all? Perhaps I have not posed the question correctly(I think I may have)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work for the first page when the input box is submitted. To get it to work after returning to the page you need to also check the $_SESSION variable you have set. You could try adding an or section to your if statement such as.

```
if (!isset($_POST['sameasbilling']) && $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] != "1") {
     $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = "";
} else { 
print ' checked="checked"';
    $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = "1";

}
```

**Edit

```
if(isset($_POST['your_submit_button'])){
        if (isset($_POST['sameasbilling'])) {
            print ' checked="checked"';
            $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = "1";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = "";
        }
    }else if ($_SESSION['sameasbilling'] == "1") {
        print ' checked="checked"';
    }
```

Comment: This works, but I'm presented with a problem I've had before where, the session is not able to be reset to == "" if I untick the box and submit the form. It always stays ticked because the session['sameasbilling'] doesn't get updated. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Try the updated version, instead it checks both aren't set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But its not catching if the user has changed the tickbox while on the page. So for example the user submits the form with the first name field empty and the tick box ticked, the page runs itself and comes back to itself with an error regarding the first name field and the tick box ticked thanks to your code. However the user then decides to just untick the box and resubmit the form still with the first name field empty. The page refreshes but the tickbox is still ticked when it should be unticked. Is there a way to reset the $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] if this happens?

Comment: I'm running a bit slow this morning. Tried another revision. Check if the user has submitted the form first, if they have go off the form fields otherwise use session variables.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to have worked perfectly! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`headers_sent()` checks if your script has already send something to the header, for example if you dumped some text to the output buffer before asking that it would return true.

I think you mean

```
if ($_SESSION['sameasbilling']){
    header("Location: order-confirm.php");
    exit();
}
```

or if you're sending the checkbox value again skip the session bit here

```
if (isset($_POST['sameasbilling'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this more logic, assuming the `$_POST['sameasbilling']` is a checkbox, I'll do it like that :

```
if(isset($_POST['sameasbilling']) && !empty($_POST['sameasbilling']))
    $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = 1;
else
    $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] = 0;

if (isset($_POST)) //or check if the submit has been sent or even the session
{
    //send user to next page
    header("Location: order-confirm.php");
    exit();
}
else
    die("Not Sent"); //or set the header location to the previous page with an error
```

Than

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sameasbilling" name="sameasbilling" value="1" <?php echo $_SESSION['sameasbilling'] == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : '';?> />
```